# Code igniter base_url bugging, or url_rewriting?

Tags: codeigniter, url, base-url, rewriting

Thanks in advance for all the help you will give me guys.
I am kind of desperate now, I do not know what to do. I guess the problem comes from my base_url, but it can also come from my .htaccess that has url_rewriting on ?
I have a code igniter project that works on localhost.

Whenever I click on a link, it adds a "localhost:8888" :

I have a page with following url : http://localhost:8888/my_project/
And when I click on a link on this page, it points me to : 
http://localhost:8888/localhost:8888/my_project/procedure/student

I do not get why it adds that localhost:8888 in between ? (if I manually take off the localhost:8888 in the url, the page works and loads correctly)

Here is my constants file defining my base_url :

```
define("URL", (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define("SITE_URL", 'http://localhost:8888/my_project/');
```

Here is my .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

## in case the URL is not an actual FILE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

## or an actual directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

## send everything to the index, for MVC
#RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Here is also my config.php base_url line :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http:/localhost:8888/my_project/';
```

The links are generated in the view as follows : id);?> so that should give for example localhost:8888/my_project/teacher/7 but when I hover the link there is localhost:8888/localhost:8888/my_project/teacher/7

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Base URL requires scheme too (i.e. `http://localhost:8888/my_project/`). Pay attention on __http://__ part. It is mandatory part. When that one is not set you could get result that is  describing your issue there. Double check `$config['base_url']` value again and also you can read comment above that line in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` file.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer mate. I just edited my post so you can see my config.php file and base_url was already set. I just forgot to mention it dumbly. I just don't get your last sentence : "and also you can read comment above that line in APPPATH.'config/config.php" What did you mean ? What is APPATH ? What line in which file do I have to comment ? Thanks in advance mate :)

Comment: `APPPATH` is constant that points to `ROOT.'application/'` directory. Your assumption is right, above that (base url) line in config file, there is comment block describing how base url should be set. Regarding your issue here, can you `var_dump()` that link in controller with exiting before you load the view and checking what value you have got there? That part of controller would be appreciated here to let us get better understanding of problem. In example: is it happening when you are using your custom made constants or in some other case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer mate. Okay, I have no APPATH constant in my constants.php file. And to answer your question I guess it is happening when using my custom made constants since I defined by myself some constants as you can see previously (site_url, url, etc). The links cannot be var_dumped in the controller since they are generated in the view as follows : <a href="<?= base_url("teacher/" . $v->id);?> so that should give for example localhost:8888/my_project/teacher/7 but when I hover the link there is localhost:8888/localhost:8888/my_project/teacher/7

Comment: Of ourse it can be var_dumped in controller - everything in view just existed in controller first. I assume it would be something like `$v` or `$data[$v]` or something similar. But this shooting in the dark blindly guessing your controller code is very hard for me (probably for other ready to help developers too) and you would need to set that part of controller into question if you expect some help here.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for your answer I really appreciate your help mate :) As I said the link is created in the view as follows :  <a href="<?= base_url("teacher/" . $v->id);?> the only thing that existed in the controller is the $v->id. So what should I var_dump exactly ? The link cannot be var dumped in the controller since it is not in the controller. If you want I can var dump it in the view?

Comment: You can `var_dump(base_url());exit;` and check it what is meant under that one first.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not even think about that, am I stupid or what... base_url returns a correct base_url : string(32) "http:/localhost:8888/my_project/" So the problem does not come from the controller but from the view. Am I right ? Because the base_url is working fine in controller, but seems to not work fine on view... ?

Comment: Can't say much without seeing the code. Edit your question and post exact view block.

Comment: Also assuming `http://localhost:8888` is server root, you can set `RewriteBase /my_project/` in your htaccess file. Just noticed that you have typo in base_url - you have one instead two slashes. I believe it could be the reason of this buggy behavior.

Comment: Tpojka you're one of those geniuses I like and would need to be given the medal of honnor. Thank you so much. You saved a lot of trouble to me, omg. I still can't believe I made such a stupid mistake... Thank you so much! Have a wonderful day. Could you please post this comment as an answer so I can specify it as the correct answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After series of debugging (through [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713020/code-igniter-base-url-bugging-or-url-rewriting?noredirect=1#comment86440470_49713020)), conclusion becomes that bug was in wrongly written base url in config file. 
It should be changed from:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http:/localhost:8888/my_project/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/my_project/';// notice double slash at beginning
```

Consequently, Medal of Honor was proposed to me and I am still thinking should I take it for pointing this silly mistake that every of us experienced once or should I wait for some biggest error ever somewhere on site and then take that deserved acknowledgment. :)